# Meanings and translation of 「いいように」

Tags: translation

I have a question about the meanings and usage of いいように. I thought that it only has one meaning, which is "to act as one wills, to do something as one wills". Like in the example below.

> 彼らは、いいように[操]{あやつ}られている。
>
> They are being led by the nose.

At least before I saw the dialogue below, specifically this sentence - あくまでもいいように[捉]{とら}えればと言うことだが。. I was told that here いいように has the meaning same as よい方. And as far as I can understand, translation would sound something like "But only if I take it from the positive side." or "But only positively speaking.". Unfortunately I couldn't find this meaning/translation in dictionaries. So, could you please explain me the this expression.

> 鈴:「じゃ、それで何か楽しいことしないと損じゃない？」
>
> 私:「[損得勘定]{そん・とく・かん・じょう}の問題でもないように思いますけどね、これは」
>
> 鈴:「なにさ、[相変]{あい・か}わらず細かいなー君は」
>
> 鈴さんが[鷹揚]{おう・よう}過ぎるのだと思う。あくまでもいいように捉えればと言うことだが。

Comment: 捉える=とらえる here, not つかまえる

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are discussing two meanings of 「`いいように`」 here:

1. At X's will; In whatever way that's convenient to X; As X likes
2. (quite literally) In a good manner; In a positive way; Rightly; Nicely

The first `いいように` is an idiom, usually used with certain verbs such as 「`扱う`」「`利用する`」「`あしらう`」. It's not interchangeable with 「`よい方に`」 or 「`よく`」. Very often this `いいように` implies this person X is evil. That's why it's in dictionaries. (If it's *you* who asks to treat yourself freely, then there is no evil sense: 「私のことはいいように使ってください。 」 = "Please use me as you like.")

The second meaning is quite literal, and that's why you couldn't find it in dictionaries. 「`いいように捉【とら】える`」 is literally translated as "catch (it) in a good way", and you really have いいように translated this 「いいように」.