# Understanding どう転んでもいいように高校だけは出ておきなさい

Tags: grammar, nuances

Dad tells his son who is in high school this phrase

> どう転んでもいいように高校だけは出ておきなさい

I have difficulty comprehending the whole meaning of this phrase.

どう転んでも is some kind of idiom meaning "no matter how you do" right?

What いいように means here? According to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16315/meanings-and-translation-of-%e3%81%84%e3%81%84%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab), it can either mean "like/as good" (ie. "in a good manner") or "in such way that (to achieve one's own) good." I don't know which meaning fits in this context.

I know that 高校を出る means "to graduate from high school." But when だけは replaces を, how the meaning change? "graduate *only* from high school"? I'm confused what は is doing after だけ. If I interpret it as a contrastive は, then it makes だけ redundant. Is it a topic marker?

This is how I understand the overall meaning of this phrase

> No matter how you do, just graduate from high school for your sake!

Did I get it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## いいように

ように here means "in order to". So your second interpretation is correct.

## だけ vs だけは

I personally don't differentiate between contrastive and topic marker for は, so I don't know how to answer that question but, だけ means "only", whereas だけは means "if nothing else". In this case,

> 高校だけ出ておきなさい

would mean "Finish up to high school only (do not go to college, or anything further)". While,

> 高校だけは出ておきなさい

would mean, "If nothing else, finish high school (whether you go to college after that is not important/out of the scope of this conversation)".

So the whole sentence would be something like

> If nothing else, finish high school, so that you can keep your options open.

(I'm assuming どう転んでも refers to the listener's prospects after high school.)

Comment: 転ぶ here means "(for things) to (randomly) turn out", so "prepare for anything to happen" or "prepare for the worst" is the basic idea of どう転んでもいいように. I think this son is trying to choose a path that has a low chance of success (sport player, YouTuber, etc).